# How to I stop Jupyter Notebooks from creating and opening the HTML file?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Whenever I start a Jupyter Notebook, it creates and automatically opens an HTML file. How do I stop this? HTML files are opened by default on my system in my text editor, not my web browser, and my terminal allows me to click links to open them, and the link to the notebook is in the output of the command, so I don't need the link in the HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have thought of it first, but the help file answered the question (`jupyter notebook --help`):

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser
```